# Is a sphere really a (differentiable) manifold?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am a beginning student in Differential Geometry. According to what I understand, the charts:

$$\sigma_+^z(x,y) = (x,y, \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} )$$
$$\sigma_+^x(u,v)  = (\sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2},u,v )$$

defined on $U_+^z = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 <1 \} $ and $U_+^x = \{ (u,v) : u^2 + v^2 <1\}$ respectively will cover only a portion of the sphere and omitting the points $(0,\pm1,0).$

Now my question goes, how exactly does one find the transition map $$\sigma_+^z{^{-1}} \circ \sigma_+^x$$ when both coordinate charts/surface patches is a map from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$?

I already tried solving for an inverse, but I can't figure out what to do with the square root component $\sqrt{}$ for $\sigma_+^z$?

I conjecture that the radius is actually a variable as well and that's why I am having so much trouble?

**Goal**: My goal is to compute a transition map for a chart mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. I've looked all over all the notes in differential geometry to find one example of a transition map calculation, I could not find any, that's why I am making one right now. If you could at least lead me to a simpler manifold (surface, I guess in this case), it would be great. I think I would be able to do the algebra from there. (sorry this post is so long)

**What I tried "solving for variables"**:

For $\sigma_+^z$, I set $s = x$, $t = y$, and $r = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$, since the first two variables have been solved, I am not sure what to do with the last one.

For $\sigma_-^x$, I set $a = \sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2}, b  = u$ and $c = v$, does this mean the inverse will map back to $$ (\sqrt{1 - a^2 - c^2} , c)  \subset U_+^x$$

Comment: Why would radius be a variable? It's a sphere, after all.

Comment: I meant in spherical coordinates.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The radius isn't changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first coordinate chart $\sigma_+^z$ parametrizes the hemisphere $H_+^z = \{z > 0\}$, and the second one $\sigma_+^x$ parametrizes the hemisphere $H_+^x = \{x > 0\}$.  The inverse of $\sigma_+^z$ on $H_+^z$ is
$$(\sigma_+^z)^{-1}(x,y,z) = (x,y)$$
("solve for the variables", right?).  From this you can compute the transition map to be
$$(\sigma_+^z)^{-1} \sigma_+^x \colon (u,v) \mapsto (\sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2}, u)$$
which is smooth since $\lVert (u,v) \rVert < 1$.  You should be able to fill in the details there.

Comment: Some information i missing here. When you collapse down to $\mathbb{R}^2$, what happened to $z = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$ in the third component for $\sigma_+^z$?

Comment: I mean I set $s = x, t = y, r = \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$ (so I didn't actually call it $z$)

Comment: @sidht Think about it for a moment.  You are trying to invert $\sigma_+^z$, which means you have to solve for $(x,y)$ in the equation $(s,t,r) = (x,y,\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$.  So $(x,y) = (s,t)$; i.e. the inverse function sends a triple to its first two coordinates.

Comment: okay, but doesn't this mean the inverse of patches/charts of the form $(x,y,f(x,y))$ will lose its "information" when we collapse down back to two-dimensional? This type of parametrization seems "dangerous"

Comment: @Ryam Reich, also I figured out the transition map traces the curve  to $x^2 + y^2 = 1 - v^2$, where this should still be a circle, but how do I make the argument that $v < 1$?

Comment: @sidht You have to take into account on what set the inverse function is defined.  We have $\sigma_+^z \colon U_+^z \to H_+^z$, from the unit disk to the upper hemisphere, so its inverse goes the other way, $(\sigma_+^z)^{-1} \colon H_+^z \to U_+^z$.  It *does* "forget" the $z$-coordinate, but the information is not lost in the sense that the function's domain still contains it.  It can be reconstructed because the points of the domain are placed at the correct height already.  I don't get your second question.

Comment: @Ryam Reich My question is this: The cartesian equation of the map $(\sqrt{1 - u^2 - v^2}, u)$ is $x^2 + y^2 = 1 - v$ right? How do I know that $v < 1$? I know its contained back in the $U_+$, but I can't find a way to make the inequalities work.

Comment: @sidht I think you mean $= 1 - v^2$.  In any case I don't see how this computation is relevant.

Comment: I just computed it to see what the map geometrically means.

Comment: Oh.  Well, in that case, the answer is that since $(u,v)$ is in $U_+^x$ by assumption, we have to have $v < 1$.  You can't just work with formulas; you must also know the domain.

Comment: A moment of thought made me realize that is the answer. But what would happen if one of the domain is not a circle?

Comment: Then you would have to analyze it differently and the answer would depend on what it is.  In any case, I think I have said enough about this.

Comment: Alright, I'll save that for another question.